# How is 3.11 pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation

When referring to the earthquake, tsunami and nuclear incident, is "3.11" pronounced "San gatsu ju ichi nichi", or is there a shortened version, like "nine one one" or "September eleven" for the terrorist attacks on September the eleventh?

Comment: Isn't it usually pronounced with the "th" as in "September eleventh"?

Comment: @silvermaple: it ought to, but it isn't. Which is my point.

Comment: 3/11 is typically much more common in Western media (who probably like that 9/11 ring to it)... Japanese media overwhelmingly prefer the term 大震災/東日本大震災.

Comment: I thought "nine one one" was the number you dialed in emergencies in the US. I thought "nine eleven" was more common.

Comment: @dainichi. There is an urban legend that said that the emergency number "nine one one" was initially called "nine eleven", but it got renamed because there were people who couldn't find number eleven on the phone.

Comment: @Flaw: that claim is stated as fact in Wikipedia With citations given: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/9-1-1#cite_ref-35

Comment: @AndrewGrimm. Wow I did not know it was actually a fact.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: No, what I mean is that whenever I say it, or hear it, it's September 11th or 911...

Comment: ＞there were people who couldn't find number eleven on the phone. --- Lol in Japan we have ひゃくとうばん but no one would say 'I can't find number ten on the phone!'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `2.26事件` or `5.15事件`, I remember learning them to be read as "にいにいろくじけん", "ごういちごうじけん," but I also hear people reading them as "にいてんにいろくじけん", "ごうてんいちごうじけん." Other than these two, as far as I know, incidents written like this seem to be read simply as if you read a number with a decimal point, like "さんてんいちいち."

Comment: Is the vowel sound for に and ご intentionally dragged out to form にい and ごう? Why does it happen?

Comment: @Flaw That is the way these numbers are usually pronounced in isolation.

Comment: @Flaw One-mora digits are given an extra mora when pronouncing a series of digits, probably to make them an "equidistant" rythm.